# Using JavaScript to highlight column based on dropdown list selection

Tags: javascript, css

I have a data table with a dropdown box that sorts the table by column.  I am trying to highlight the column that is selected/sorted by the dropdown.  I am using the following code to obtain the index of the dropdown item:

```
 <script>
 var sel = document.getElementById('asorting').selectedIndex;
 alert(sel);
 </script>
```

I am using the following CSS code to highlight the column:

```
 <style>
 table td:nth-of-type(3)
 {
 background-color:#E0E0E0;
 }
 </style>
```

Both of these work on their own, but I am trying to update the "table td:nth-of-type(3)" to change based on the value of my sel variable.  I have tried using (" + sel + ") to feed the variable to the CSS, but that is not working.

I am not very experienced in JS and have not been able to find anything on this site that relates exactly to what I am trying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can define a css class with background-color and add the classname to the matching element by js.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will see if I can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle classes in javascript by arriving at a logic like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function changeStyle(v){
                elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hightlight');       
                if(elements.length > 0){
                    for (let element of elements){
                        element.classList.remove('hightlight');
                    }
                }       
                document.getElementById('data').children[parseInt(v)-1].className = "hightlight";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .hightlight {
                color : red
            }
        </style>
        <select id="asorting" onchange="changeStyle(this.value)">
            <option class="row" value="1">one</option>
            <option class="row" value="2">two</option>
            <option class="row"value="3">three</option>
        </select>
        <table>
            <tbody id="data">
                <tr>
                    <td>one</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>two</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>three</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might work but not the best solution and not at all recommended if the number of options are more.

Comment: Thank you. One issue I failed to mention is that I am using the low-code platform Caspio, and I am not creating the drop-down myself, which is why I was looking at using the index value. I will see if I can  modify this as it is a great starting place.

Comment: If possible could you share the html for the drop-down

Comment: A .jpg showing the code for the dropdown can be found here: [link](https://tc-data.com/files/dropdownHTML.jpg).  My initial thought was that, based on the index of the dropdown, I could change the td:nth-of-type CSS to highlight the sorted column.  I don't see the HTML for the dropdown using the element inspector, and the classes identified all appear to relate to the dropdown box itself rather than to the sort options. The CSS can be seen in [link](https://tc-data.com/files/dropdownCSS.jpg). Thank you for your help!